# Открытие нескольких окон по таймеру

Tags: c#, winforms

По таймеру делаю проверку на появление новых записей в бд и с появлением новой записи необходимо открыть окно с деталями этой записи. 
если делаю по таймеру, то Окна открываются но неотрисованные до конца болтаются на экране и доступа к ним нет. окно как бы на .Show() висит... 
Если делаю не по таймеру а кликом на кнопке, то все открылись отрисовались и всё ок.

```
async void showwins()
        {
            while (1==1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    SmallWin f = new SmallWin($"{i}:{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
                    var d = await Task.Run(()=>showsinglewin(i,f));

                }
            }
        }

        int showsinglewin(int i, SmallWin w)
        {            
            w.Show();
            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь открыть окно в потоке из пула потоков. Так не делается. Работайте с окнами только из вашего UI  потока.

Comment: `while (1==1)` можно просто `while(true)`

Comment: tym: не понял если честно... async, await, Task.Run() это я уже экспериментировал. while(1==1) это для простоты примера. по таймеру просто вызываю функцию showins(), в которой просто создаются несколько окон. таймер в главной форме.

Comment: я б всю эту штуку сокетами обыграл...

Comment: вы знаете, что такое поток (Thread)? Вы знаете про основной поток UI приложений? Вы работали уже с диспетчером?

Comment: Если вы ко мне обращаетесь, указывайте мой ник вот так @tym32167 - иначе я не получу оповещение о сообщении.

Comment: @tym32167 : Thread использовал, про основной поток UI только немного теории. смысл понимаю. если запускаю таймером каждое окошко в отдельном Thread, то окошки открываются и тутже исчезают.

Comment: Смотрите. Вы не можете открыть окно просто в любом потоке. Чтобы оно работала в потоке, поток должен быть настроен определенным образом. Когда вы запускаете ваше приложение, при старте такой настроенный поток создается сам. У каждого элемента интерфейса в формах есть специальный метод для доступа к подобному потоку. Я точно не помню, как этот метод называется (с телефона гуглить не хочу), но попробуйте вызвать в окне `this.Invoke(()=> new mywindow().show());`. Важно в этом коде понять, что ваше окно mywindow должно быть и создано и запущено только в уи потоке.

Comment: @tym32167 : this.Invoke - это в главной форме, в той же где таймер? т.е. this - это Основная форма? если так, то Ошибка: Не удается преобразовать лямбда выражение к типу Делегат...

Comment: Добавил пример для вас.

Comment: `this.Invoke - это в главной форме, в той же где таймер?` - да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать обычный таймер, но тогда вам надо будет позаботиться о запуске окна в нужном потоке. Или вы можете использовать DispatcherTimer, но тогда весь метод будет запущен в UI потоке (то есть нельзя в таком методе использовать бесконечные циклы, повесите всё приложение).

Пример:

```
public class MainForm:Form
{
    System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    DispatcherTimer _dTimer;

    public MainForm()
    {
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        _dTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _dTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(13);
        _dTimer.Tick+= DispatcherTimerCallback;
        _dTimer.Start();

        this.FormClosing+= FormClosingCallback;


    }

    private void FormClosingCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dTimer.Stop();
        _timer.Dispose();
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var form = new Form() {Text = "TimerCallback form"};
            form.Show();
        }));
    }

    private void DispatcherTimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new Form() { Text = "DispatcherTimerCallback form" };
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

Как использовать

```
new MainForm().ShowDialog();
```

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!! заработало. я не знал такой записи: new Action(() =>
        {
            var form = new Form() {Text = "TimerCallback form"};
            form.Show();
        })

Comment: @aberg пожалуйста. Если ответ вам помог, отметье его галочкой.